# How to read example.PDF in a Android 11 app from '/storage/emulated/0/Documents/example.PDF' without user interaction?

Tags: android, pdf, android-11, scoped-storage

After upgrading to Android 11,  my app can no longer access /storage/emulated/0/Documents/ the way it was previously working.

It appears if I use the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent the user will be prompted to interact with the file system. Is there a way to do this without user interaction? User clicks the print button, pdf is loaded from /storage/emulated/0/Documents/example.PDF, converted to jpg, and sent to a printer.

Comment: No. User interaction is needed unless you obtained 'all files access'.